# Eucalyptus 4.4.4 Windows image installation has no prep tool?

Tags: windows, image, iso, eucalyptus

The installation document mentions download of latest windows image preparation tool [here](https://docs.eucalyptus.cloud/eucalyptus/4.4.4/index.html#shared/images_win_wis.html) but the link points to deprecated eucalyptus [website](http://downloads.eucalyptus.com/software/tools/windows-prep/). Where can we download this tool? Has anyone installed windows image on eucalyptus 4.4.4?

Answer (score 0):

The Windows prep tool is available here:

https://downloads.eucalyptus.cloud/software/tools/windows-prep/windows-prep-tools-3.5.0.iso
https://downloads.eucalyptus.cloud/software/tools/windows-prep/windows-prep-tools-3.4.0.iso
https://downloads.eucalyptus.cloud/software/tools/windows-prep/windows-prep-tools-3.2.0.iso
https://downloads.eucalyptus.cloud/software/tools/windows-prep/windows-prep-tools-3.1.0.iso

but note that this tool has not been tested with Eucalyptus 4.4.4.